# NetworkManager libnm thread safety

Tags: c, network-programming, glib

I'm trying to use NetworkManager's libnm binding from a multithreaded program. Is libnm thread safe? I could not found any information about it.

Answer (score 1):

[libnm](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/index.html) is written using [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/) and [gobject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/). Although they don't seem to explicitly mention it in their doc, in general anything that uses glib runs on [the main event loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) and expects that the API will only be called on the main event loop (ie: on the thread that the event loop runs on).

Glib itself, however, is thread safe in general, or provides ways to ensure thread safety.  For example, to connect to signal of libnm, you can use [g_signal_connect](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect) from any thread; however the signal handler which you provide will be invoked on the thread running the main loop. Also, you can use something like [g_idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) from any thread, in order to schedule a function to be called from the main event loop.

You can also use the [GTask](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html) lib to help you with threading in glib. Thre is more info about the [Glib main context here](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/unstable/main-contexts.html.en).